# I'm running ubuntu 18.04 LTS should I update to 20.04 when it comes out or should I do a clean install?

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, updates, lts, 20.04

2 years ago I decided to move to Ubuntu and decided to go with the LTS version. For 2 years everything has been going great. Next month the new LTS version is going to come up. What does people do in this case? Upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04 or do a clean install and start anew with 20.04?

Comment: The upgrade pass will apear in summer with 20.04.1 release.

Comment: @Pilot6 So for now at the release I can only do a clean install. Interesting.

Comment: You can do whatever you want. But the official path appears with the first point release.

Comment: The less you have customize your system, the better an upgrade will work.  Ubuntu tends to wait for upgrade to make sure they catch most bugs.  Can also keep using 18.04 for a few more years so needing to upgrade is not a time constant.  Can also get the newest and bestest(?) right now without waiting if you don't mind it might have bugs, with a clean install or as dual boot to test it out.